# Docker build is not working - It does not find the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, dockerfile, quarkus, docker-build

I am trying to build a quarkus container with docker file, but look like that docker build is not finding the Dockerfile. I have changed the name of the Dockerfile but anyway is not working.

I run: docker build src/main/docker/native.dockerfile

And there is the error:

```
 docker build src/main/docker/native.dockerfile
[+] Building 0.1s (1/2)
 => ERROR [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 97B                                                                                                                           0.0s
------
 > [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: walk src\main\docker\native.dockerfile: System cannot find specified path.
```

Here is a print:

[image: Print]

Even if I run with the intellij it throw another error:

[image]

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal
WORKDIR /work/
COPY target/*-runner /work/application
RUN chmod 775 /work
CMD ./application -Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Dquarkus.http.port=${PORT}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The argument to `docker build` is a directory name, not a file name; you need a `docker build -f` option if the build script isn't named `Dockerfile`.  Where you say "it throws an error" you put an image file instead of the error; can you replace the image with the actual output of the build command?

Comment: @DavidMaze `docker build -f` still does not working. There is the error:

`docker build -f src/main/docker/native.dockerfile
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, speaking of -f flag, the command:

```
docker build -f src/main/docker/native.dockerfile
```

will not work, as you mentioned, but I think it is important for me to explain why. The reason is - **you did not specify the build context for Dockerfile**. When you typing something like this:

```
docker build src/main/docker/native.dockerfile
```

It will lookup for Dockerfile, called ***Dockerfile***, but the **src/main/docker/native.dockerfile will act as an context of build**. In other words, when you coping something to your image, docker needs to understand, from where exactly you want to copy files/directories. So you can assign whatever name your want to your Dockerfile, just remember about the build context (It can be either relative or absolute)

Now let me address errors you encoutered :)

You got 2 different problems, roughly speaking. First of them is - when you ran:

```
docker build /build/context/path
```

docker engine was not able to determine the context. I do not use docker on windows, but I am pretty sure this is because of separators. If I were you I will simply change directory (just to ease your life) to one which represents your build context (I assume this is the same directory, where is your Dockerfile is situated), and simply run:

```
docker build --file native.dockerfile .
```

But you will get the problem, that you have got in Intelij. **This is completely another problem.** The reason of it - when docker was copying files to your image from the host machine, it was not able to find suitable (in regards to your wildcard) files to copy. I do not see you target directory - it does not present on the screenshots, so, I cannot suggest anything further, but the problem is there. Fell free to attach them and lets investigate together :)

Have a nice day!